# Edit .htaccess to redirect multiple domains to one domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We're having an issue routing our website to it's new domain. We have a total of 3 domains.

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

Where domain3.com is the new domain that domain1.com and domain2.com need to directed to.

Our current .htaccess file is setup link so:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.com.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain3.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**What's working:**

domain2.com successfully redirects to domain3.com

domain3.com successfully goes to domain3.com

**What's not working:**

domain1.com DOES NOT redirect to domain3.com

What must be changed in the htaccess file to get domain1.com to also redirect permanently to domain3.com?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. The domain2.com still redirected, but not domain1.com

Comment: Make sure to test in a new browser. Also are you sure DocumentRoot of domain1 is same as that of domain2?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. Also, I did test in a new browser. Is there any reason to believe something on the server might have changed to cause it to not work? Sorry if that assumption seems far fetched.

Comment: create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain1.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value. Do same for `http://domain2.com/info.php`